# Swift error: use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning Swift and iOS platform. I can't get this error to go away. I've searched and haven't found anything this basic. Help is appreciated.

```
import Foundation

let num1 = 10
let num2 = 5

// declare the function answerResult, which takes and Int
// and returns a string 

func answerResult(answer : Int) ->String
    if check(num1, num2, answer) {
       return "correct!" 
    }
    else {
       Return "I'm sorry, that's wrong."
    }
}
// Call the function with various numbers 
answerResult(15)
answerResult(0)
answerResult(600)
answerResult(5)
```

> Playground execution failed:  /var/folders/c8/6w5z3zbx1477cqv1wcys2cd80000gn/T/./lldb/441/playground551 .swift :12:8: error: use of unresolved identifier 'check'
>       if check(num1, num2, answer) {

Comment: so, do you have `check` function declared anywhere?

Comment: Thanks, i see what's happening...I think? 
I'll try the func check() idea, from below.  
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'check' keyword in Swift. You're calling a nonexistant method. You probably need to implement a function *func check()* having the 3 parameters you want as input so the check actually performs operations.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll try this.